# python3 -Calander 's month_abbr returns first index empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started with Python3. I had a problem where I had to iterate over all Months (in Mmm e.g Jan) format. I used Python3 Calendars manth_abbr to get things done. here is sample code

```
 import calendar                                             

 all_months = list(calendar.month_abbr)
 print(all_months)
```

This code works fine but to my surprise.It was returning first index as empty string .here is sample output.

`['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']`

Why  I am getting first index as empty string ?

Comment: So what would the name of month `0` be? Take into account the calendar numbers months starting at *one*!

Answer (score 0):

This is to allow the month numbering start from 1 (as stated in the docs), since list/array indexing starts from zero:

> This follows normal convention of January being month number 1, so it
>   has a length of 13 and `month_abbr[0]` is the **empty string**.
>   [*Emphasis mine*]